# TextFormFields not getting focus - Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Currently I am working on login screen.
Below is how my screen must work.

1. User have 2 options to login/register. With email or mobile number.
2. User can select how they want to login/register from the option given on the screen.
3. All my TextFormFields are getting displayed as per the choice made by user (they are not visible together).

So, the difficulty I am facing here is my TextFormFields are not getting focused as per user selection. Default focus must be on mobile number field which is working fine but when user selects email option then focus is not going on email textbook and that's why keyboard also not getting displayed.Same happening with passport textbox which must be focused once user enters email address.

I have attached video link for more clarity. 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1GbOeJhftI4hIkT4RTROoQ1DoYRoWh5gu/view?usp=sharing

below is the code for all 3 Textformfields.Same code for other two textfields with controller and focus node diffrent.

```
   final emailInputController = TextEditingController();
      final mobileInputController = TextEditingController();
      final passwordInputController = TextEditingController();
      final emailFocusNode = FocusNode();
      final mobileFocusNode = FocusNode();
      final passwordFocusNode = FocusNode();

    TextFormField(
                                        autofocus: true,
                                        focusNode: passwordFocusNode,
                                        onFieldSubmitted: (a) {
                                          _handleSubmittedMobile(a);
                                        },
                                        keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                                        controller: passwordInputController,
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                          fontSize: 20.0,
                                          color: Theme.of(context)
                                              .primaryColorDark,
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                        ),
                                        )),
    TextFormField(
                                        autofocus: true,
                                        focusNode: mobileFocusNode,
                                        onFieldSubmitted: (a) {
                                          _handleSubmittedMobile(a);
                                        },
                                        keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                                        controller: mobileInputController,
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                          fontSize: 20.0,
                                          color: Theme.of(context)
                                              .primaryColorDark,
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                        ),
                                        )),
    TextFormField(
                                        autofocus: true,
                                        focusNode: emailFocusNode,
                                        onFieldSubmitted: (a) {
                                          _handleSubmittedMobile(a);
                                        },
                                        keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                                        controller: emailInputController,
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                          fontSize: 20.0,
                                          color: Theme.of(context)
                                              .primaryColorDark,
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                        ),
                                        )),
```

How i can achieve this working?

thanks in advance.

Comment: I tried your code in dartpad and its working fine. First `TextFormField` is autofocused. Do you see any errors? You can copy and paste [this code](https://gist.github.com/ratnadeep007/6c8d1a0c538fb15f0757c06da77f4307) code in [Dartpad](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/b6409e10de32b280b8938aa75364fa7b) to check.

Comment: yes first field is autofocused as its a first choice given to user. But what if user wants to login with email and password? Thats why there is an option to opt for "login with email" which when user selects , mobile number text box will disappear and email text box will be shown(when this text box is displayed on screen it must autofouced which is not happening) .

Comment: Onpress of "login with email" there should be function that focuses on `emailFocusNode` which is `onPressed: () => FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(emailFocusNode),` and use a variable of `bool` type of determine when to show mobile number input field. If this what you want I will post whole code as answer.

Comment: hello , this link you can use to check. keyboards not getting displayed as per users selection. https://gist.github.com/githubaamod/9c2625e11fc04a2bd0a7684456bba004

Comment: I think there is an error in flutter framework itself. Not sure about it. Getting error `"RenderBox was not laid out: RenderEditable#81c2f NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT"` which I found bug report in github of flutter. Do check it out. [Bug report](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/47235). Think we have to wait till its fixed.